# Ready server with a queue of tasks

Tags: python, server

If you don't like this question, please recommend improvements

Could you please recommend python libraries for this archirecture [image]

Idea of the work

1. The user makes requests to the server
2. If there is a free thread, then we perform the task
   Otherwise, we are waiting for the release of the thread

Answer (score 1):

Python standard library has what you want : [`threading`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html), [`queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html), [`http.server`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html).
All were among the first results for a Google search "python3 XXX".